# How to update an object from a VF Page using a Button?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, class

Is it possible to update an Object from a Vf page while pushing a button.

We have this Object (Products) and it has almost 500 fields and some of the triggers are fired when the object is updated, for now it has to be an human interaction by clicking on 'Edit' and 'Save'. So my goal is to create a VF Page (Updates) which has a button and allows me to update products object when I click on it. This will be huge because some other Objects are having the same problem. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Short answer is yes, but we need a lot more information on what you are trying to do to actually provide you with any help.

Comment: Ok, we have this Object (Products) and it has almost 500 fields and some of the triggers are fired when the object is updated, for now it has to be an human interaction by clicking on 'Edit' and 'Save'. So my goal is to create a VF Page (Updates) which has a button and allows me to update products object when I click on it. This will be huge because some other Objects are having the same problem. Please let me know if you need more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its possible. The command button will look like:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!updateObject}" value="Update"/>
```

The method in the controller will look something like:

```
public PageReference updateObject() {
    myObject.dateField__c = Date.today();
    update myObject;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, I just want to make sure if this code will update the whole object?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "update the whole object"

Comment: Sorry that was a silly question.. I am very new in apex. Let say I want to use a date field in the object and while I click the button I want to display today's date and Update the object, how would you do that? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Ive updated my answer so that it sets a date field to the current date. The update will cause all the update triggers you have on that object to fire.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it and let you know the outcome

Comment: This is how I create my class do you see anything wrong with it?: public class  PageReference_updateObject {
public PageReference_updateObject() {
 list<NRProducts__c> nrp= [Select Refreshed_Date__c FROM NRProducts__c];

   for (NRProducts__c  nr: nrp)
    nr.Refreshed_Date__c = Date.today();
    update nr;
    return null;
}
}

Comment: Keep in mind that this approach does make your code unsecured from CSRF perspective, if it's packaged code it would fail the Salesforce Security review, i've got a blog entry about Custom buttons and VF pages, covering this and other aspects here if you need more thoughts, http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/16/how-to-call-apex-code-from-a-custom-button/

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for the information. Could you please help me to create this controller.

Comment: @user6829 have a read through my blog entry which does just that, feel free to ask further specific questions on SE and/or my blog if you want.